# How to Optimize Hibernate buildSessionFactory();

Tags: java, hibernate

**How to Optimize Hibernate buildSessionFactory();"

The method 'cfg.buildSessionFactory();' of Hibernate consumes a lot of CPU. And on low-end systems is taking more than 20 seconds.
Is there anyway I can cache it and just load manually?

Im stuck on optimizing this. Whats the proper way to make 'cfg.buildSessionFactory();' faster?

```
public static void initHibernate() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Initializing Hibernate.....");
    String username = Cryptographer.decrypt(MySettings.getDb_username());
    String password = Cryptographer.decrypt(MySettings.getDb_password());
    String url = Cryptographer.decrypt(MySettings.getDb_url());


    cfg = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username)
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password)
            .setProperty(username, url);
    
    //Error: Hibernate Could not deserialize cache file:
    //File fileAux = new File("A:\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
    //cfg.addCacheableFile(fileAux);
    
    sessions = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

**Additional Information:**

---

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '5.4.27.Final'
```

---

Mapping xml file: (I redacted private information as REDACTED)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- UPDATE OR NONE -->
        <property name ="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>

        <!-- -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        
        <!-- -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>

        <!-- Just set the correct isolation to default(1). Stops logging messages -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">1</property>

        <!-- Might Improve Performance -->
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>

        <!-- fix time zone -->
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone">UTC</property>

        <!-- hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">3</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">360</property>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>

        <!-- C3PO -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">3</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">240</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">180</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>

        <!-- Mapping -->

        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        <mapping class="br.REDACTED.models.REDACTED"/>
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**References**

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2242766

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/197521

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18305

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/topical/html_single/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html

Comment: why do you need to optimize building the session factory?  that's something that should be done once on application startup.  speed should be largely irrelevant.

Comment: It makes the application start up slowly. Cant I cache it once ?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "cache it once".  you should only be loading it once at application start.

Comment: When I start the application again, I dont want to load again.